# Cant seem to run my Maui app on my Android, system FormatException could not find any recognizable digits

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maui

Up until now,  I had no problems connecting my android via USB and running my Maui app on it. Suddenly, when I am trying to run it I get this error -(but everything works well in when I run it in window machine)

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error XAGRD7005   System.FormatException: Could not find any recognizable digits.    at System.ParseNumbers.StringToInt(String s, Int32 radix, Int32 flags, Int32* currPos)    at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value, Int32 fromBase)    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManagedResourceParser.ProcessRtxtFile(String file)    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManagedResourceParser.Parse(String resourceDirectory, String rTxtFile, IEnumerable`1 additionalResourceDirectories, Boolean isApp, Dictionary`2 resourceMap)    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateResourceDesigner.RunTask()    at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17 UI  C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.4\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets 1268

I thought it might be because of recent changes, but when I go to older version that worked on my android it still has this error..
When I press it it take me to this file - `Files\\dotnet\\packs\\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\\33.0.4\\tools\\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets`

and to this section -
`<!-- Parse primary R.java and create Resources.Designer.cs -->     <GenerateResourceDesigner       Condition="'$(_AndroidResourceDesignerFile)' != ''"         ContinueOnError="$(DesignTimeBuild)"        NetResgenOutputFile="$(_AndroidResourceDesignerFile)"       DesignTimeOutputFile="$(_AndroidManagedResourceDesignerFile)"       JavaResgenInputFile="$(_GeneratedPrimaryJavaResgenFile)"        RTxtFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)R.txt"       Namespace="$(AndroidResgenNamespace)"       ProjectDir="$(ProjectDir)"      Resources="@(_AndroidResourceDest)"         ResourceDirectory="$(MonoAndroidResDirIntermediate)"        AdditionalResourceDirectories="@(LibraryResourceDirectories)"       IsApplication="$(AndroidApplication)"       References="@(_MonoAndroidReferencePath)"       UseManagedResourceGenerator="$(_UseManagedResourceGenerator)"       DesignTimeBuild="$(DesignTimeBuild)"        JavaPlatformJarPath="$(JavaPlatformJarPath)"    />`

It says that it has to do something with parsing but I dont know of any kind of parsing I am doing, and if so it doesnt explain why it worked up until now and suddenly it doesnt.

Now I really dont know if this is related to all of this, but just before that error popped for the first time I tried to upload a png file that used to be a gif, when I tried to run it on the android it gave me errors about those files so I removed them and since then I noticed that error.

If more information is needed I'd be glad to give!
Thanks for reading

As I mentioned going to older versions still has this error and I asked a friend to try to load it from their pc and same problem.

Comment: Sounds like something got corrupted in the app or project. 1) Manually delete app from Android device. This removes some data downloaded by debugger. Then power device off, then back on. 2) Quit Visual Studio. In solution folder, delete hidden .vs folder. Delete project's android folder's .bin and .obj folders. 3) Run Visual Studio and try again.

Comment: I have tried doing all of that and sadly it still doesnt work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: According to the error, it indicates that the error occurs when trying to convert a string to a numeric value, but the string does not contain any valid digits.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT - yes, but read this in question: *"I dont know of any kind of parsing I am doing"*. It isn't in their code; its happening inside Maui code. Therefore, it is either a Maui bug, or something corrupted. But they say they have tried the steps I suggest to fix corruption. So it is strange that this started happening to them.